# SubString replacement in text

Tags: java, regex, replace, substring

I want to replace all the occurrences of a string in a text except the first one. 
for eg:

input: Example [2] This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

replaced word: sample (sImple)

output: Example [2] This is a sample text. This is a **sImple** text. This is a **sImple** text.

In string functions what I see is replace, replaceAll, replaceFirst.

How should I handle this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `replaceAll` and `replace` will replace all substrings (difference between them is that `replaceAll` uses regular expression as argument, while `replace` uses literals).
- `replaceFirst` will replace only first substring which will match pattern you want to find.

What you can do is

- use [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) method to determine indexes of first and second `sample` word,
- then [`substring(int beginIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) on index of second `sample` to get part of string from which you want to let replacing possible
- and call your `replace` method on this part
- when replacement is done you can concatenate part which shouldn't be changed (before index of second `sample` word) and part with replaced values

Other solution would be using `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` form `Matcher` class and use replacing value after you find second `sample` word. Code for it can look like

```
String yourString = "Example [2] This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("sample", Pattern.LITERAL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean firstWordAlreadyFound = false;
while (m.find()) {
    if (firstWordAlreadyFound) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "sImple");
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group());
        firstWordAlreadyFound = true;
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
Example [2] This is a sample text. This is a sImple text. This is a sImple text.
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... the whole scenario is as following:  The replacement text is in hashmap with key as the string to be replaced in the text. I am able to replace all the keys.. but I would just need to replace all except the first one. I m iterating through hashmap and then replacing. I tried your code inside the hashmap iteration.

Comment: @user2832203 Well, that is kind of important information which should be put in original question from the start. In that case you would need to create pattern which would be able match any key in your HashMap, but creating such pattern can be tricky: you would have to order keys in a way from most detailed one to less detailed one to avoid situation where pattern would be `fo|foo` because for this regex in string `foofoo` you will only match `fo` two times because in regex `fo|foo` `fo` has higher priority because it is on the left and regex is read from left to right.

Comment: @user2832203 Also we don't know if you want to find words or substrings (should `name` be matched in `surname`?). I don't see a way you could change this question to something else without making all answers loose their sense so consider accepting one of the answers as solution of problem you described in this question and create new one in which you will describe exactly what you want to do (how your input looks like - text and key-value map - be more detailed about what you want to achieve - are there any potential fals-positive matches like `name` in `surname`?).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to search:

```
((?:\bsample\b|(?<!^)\G).*?)\bsample\b
```

And this for replcement:

```
$1simple
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/1)

**Java Code:**

```
String r = input.replaceAll("((?:\\bsample\\b|(?<!^)\\G).*?)\\bsample\\b", "$1simple");
```

Comment: Yes sure. `\G` matches at start of line OR at the end of the previous match. So this regex finds string between a literal `sample` OR `end of the previous match` to next occurrence of `sample` and captures it as group #1. Then it finds a literal `sample` next to it. In the replacement it uses back reference `$1` and `simple` to replace all but first `sample` to `simple`

Comment: Thank you.. but the sample and simple are not constant in the text. The text changes with different files.

Comment: @user2832203: You can use any other search word to in place of `sample` OR any other word in place of `simple` in the code.

Comment: @vks: I just explained `\G` in my previous comment to `AvinashRaj`

Comment: is \G available in python regex or in pCRE?

Comment: Yes it is part of PCRE and I guess available in Python as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive approach:

```
public static String replaceAllButFirst(String text, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    String[] parts = text.split(toReplace, 2);
    if(parts.length == 2) {  //Found at least one match
        return parts[0] + toReplace + parts[1].replaceAll(toReplace, replacement);
    } else { //no match found giving original text
        return text;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "This is a sample test. This is a sample test. This is a sample test";
    System.out.println(replaceAllButFirst(x, "sample", "simple"));
}
```

Which will give:

```
This is a sample test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
(?<=\bsample\b)(.*?)\bsample\b
```

And replacement:

```
$1yourstring
```

**Java Code:**

```
String s=input.replaceAll("(?<=\\bsample\\b)(.*?)\\bsample\\b", "$1yourString");
```

Comment: the question is tagged as java.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `substring` and `indexOf` methods to break it in two string then replace in second string and finally append both the strings back

sample code:

```
String str = "Example [2] This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.";

String findWhat = "sample";
int index = str.indexOf(findWhat) + findWhat.length();

String temp = str.substring(0, index + 1); // first string
str = str.substring(index + 1);            // second string

//replace in second string and combine back
str = temp + str.replace(findWhat, "simple"); // final string
System.out.println(str);
```

---

combine all in few statements:

```
int index = str.indexOf(findWhat) + findWhat.length();
str = str.substring(0, index + 1) + str.substring(index + 1).replace(findWhat, "simple");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function that does exactly what you want, either in the String or StringBuilder classes. You'll need to write your own. Here's a quickie:

```
    private string ReplaceText(string originalText, string textToReplace, string replacementText)
    {
        string tempText;
        int firstIndex, lastIndex;

        tempText = originalText;
        firstIndex = originalText.IndexOf(textToReplace);
        lastIndex = tempText.LastIndexOf(textToReplace);

        while (firstIndex >= 0 && lastIndex > firstIndex)
        {
            tempText = tempText.Substring(0,lastIndex) + replacementText + tempText.Substring(lastIndex + textToReplace.Length);
            lastIndex = tempText.LastIndexOf(textToReplace);
        }

        return tempText;
    }
```